# Bloqueo <li> por medio de función javascript

Tags: javascript, html, c#, asp.net, asp

Tengo el siguiente menu

```
<nav id="sidebar">
  <div class="sidebar-header">
    <h3><b>Menu</b></h3>
    <strong>Menu</strong>
  </div>

  <ul class="list-unstyled components">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Dashboard
      </a>
      <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
        <li><a href="#">Reporte 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reporte 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reporte 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></i> Mantenimientos
      </a>
      <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
        <li><a href="#">Transportistas</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Productos</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#pageSubmenu1" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i> Seguridad
      </a>
      <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu1">
        <li><a href="UsuariosForm.aspx">Usuarios</a></li>
        <li><a href="RolesForm.aspx">Roles</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></i> Portfolio
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#homeSubmenu2" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Dashboard
      </a>
      <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu2">
        <li><a href="#">Reporte 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reporte 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reporte 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></i> FAQ
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></i> Contact
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="list-unstyled CTAs">
  </ul>
</nav>
```

que me da como resultado lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero Hacer lo siguiente que en cada opción de `<li>` tenga un id con el nombre de la opción que corresponde y con el evento `onclick` llamar un función javascript, la cual me permita hacer una conexión a una base de dato y me permita buscar buscar si tiene el permiso adecuado para poder usar esa pantalla de lo contrario que me aparezca un mensaje diciendo que no tiene permiso.

Comment: Esa validación va del lado del servidor, deberías conseguir esos permisos antes de armar el menú, así una vez que los tengas podrías poner una clase al `<li class="no-permisos">` y mostrarla deshabilitada.

Comment: ¿Es necesaria la etiqueta c#? lo digo porque no veo que la pregunta tenga que ver con c# y si con javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Es mejor que le muestres ese mensaje y bloquees el acceso desde el servidor no desde el cliente con JS. Si lo haces solo desde el cliente al pulsar el link te dirá que no tienes permiso pero si escribe el URL directamente en el navegador podrá acceder.

De todos modos, tu aplicación debería crear la plantilla correcta para cada tipo usuario y sus permisos, no mostrarle mensajes de error cuando intentan pulsar un link que les has facilitado. Es decir, no deberías mostrarle al usuario una sección a la cual no podrá acceder.

Comment: Soy muy nuevo en esto y si esa es la solución te agradezco pero no sabría como hacer todo esto.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo con jquery la funcion $.get() como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
$("button").click(function(){
$.get("demo_test.asp", function(data, status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
});
```

});

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp